# Hide loader from jwPlayer

Tags: javascript, jquery, jwplayer, jwplayer6, jwplayer7

I want to hide/remove loader from jwPlay. Just want to display a black screen or custom loader.

I have checked the document but I am not getting any kind of stuff like this. Even I have tried to hide the loader from with the CSS but I don't find any HTML content of the loader.

Comment: what loader are you referring to? are you talking about the cover image that is shown, i believe jwplayer is a BIG community and they provide all the customizations you should add the code that you have so far, so that we know where you are currently standing